# Integrating Email2Case with Office 365

Tags: email2case, office-365

I have searched here using keywords such as e2c, office 365, authentication tna.

My query concerns integrating our Java Email to Case agent with Exchange Online in our Office 365 tenant.  Specifically, how to specify the account and password.  Is the only option to specify the username and password in the Email to Case config file?  Has anybody got this working?

**Edit**

Note: The Salesforce Java Email-to-Case client is no longer available for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do need to store your credentials in a config file or your Java Jar class. That's one of the things that makes the E2C client less secure and it's why Salesforce is no longer supporting it.